Voting for duplicate or off-topic in Staging Ground should also automatically subscribe for notifications from the post
Leaving a review on a Staging Ground item does automatically subscribe for notifications from the post. And the system certainly treats voting the same as leaving a review since it immediately moves you away to give you another post to review1.
However, if you receive notifications for post changes after leaving a "Needs minor/major changes" review, you should also receive notifications if you voted off-topic or duplicate.

Somebody might dispute your vote and you should re-examine it
The post might be published and you would still need to re-review and maybe even re-apply your vote to the published question2
The Staging Ground can be updated to an extent that invalidates the vote

Whatever the case, leaving a vote is a form of leaving a review and should be handled as such. Knowing what happens with the post afterward is important when you leave a review.

1 related feature request: Allow me to stay on a Staging Ground post after I submit a review action
2 Currently this is a bug: Converting duplicate/off-topic votes after question publication from Staging Ground However, even if the SG vote was transferred to the graduated question, you might want to have another look

I think the second dupe/off-topic voter receives a notification when the post status changes (e.g. to Re-Evaluate).

I don't think the auto follow happens for other reviews as well? It used to happen during the beta but was then turned off / removed since it caused too many notifications.

Can you check whether it says "Following" or "Follow" for you once you review something not as off-topic or duplicate? For me it shows "Follow" both before and after a review.

@AbdulAzizBarkat it only says "Follow". I've had to explicitly go back and click the button to get it to actually say "Following".

@AbdulAzizBarkat "I don't think the auto follow happens for other reviews as well?" it's not an auto-follow exactly. But I get notifications for things I've reviewed. But the post itself isn't followed.

@VLAZ ah, so basically stuff like "A question you reviewed has been submitted for re-evaluation" or replies to some comments? Following will get you notifications for things like edits, etc. as well.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I think it doesn't switch to followed upon reviewing but you do get some notifications without you "following" the post (e.g. I think you get it when the OP requests re-evaluation but not when there's an edit without that).

IIUC you're only talking about subscribing to SG notifications, not the "Follow"/"Following" feature on SO posts. If so, you should probably not use the word "follow" since that sounds like the literal SO "Follow" link/feature.
